# if else syntax - php not working - getting wrong answer

Tags: php

I am getting wrong output from this if else syntax, what could be wrong here? The output should be wrong answer, but i am getting the right answer output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    $math = 22+22+22;

    if($math = 22222222) {
        echo "Right answer";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong answer";
    }

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Assignment in a conditional, as you have accidentally done here, may not always evaluate to true, although it does in your case because of the value you're using. An assignment expression like `$math = 22222222` evaluates to the assigned value, but if you assign a falsey value (`0`, `[]`, `''`, etc.) the conditional will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change `=` to `===`.

`if($math === 22222222) {`

`=` is used to assign a value to a variable

`==` is used for loose comparison

`===` is used for strict comparison

This answer right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/2595450) as pointed by Gildas gives a good explanation of how `==` is different from `===`

Comment: Allow me to augment your answer with this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp. Personnaly, I solely use similarity comparison.

Comment: @Gildas Sure, I'll add the explanation to my answer.